# Pyinstaller created exe file can not load a keras nn model

Tags: python, keras, pyinstaller

My python scrip includes:

```
from keras.models import model_from_json
model = model_from_json(open("test.json").read())
model.load_weights("test.h5")
model.compile(loss="mean_squared_error", optimizer = "adam")
```

Then, I created  an exe file using pyinstaller from aforementioned script. The exe file can not load the saved model. Any thought on that would be appreciated.

Comment: The error message would be helpful to diagnose a problem. Are you creating exe in one-file mode or one-dir mode? Is `test.h5` placed near executable?

Comment: Initially i used this:
    pyinstaller -w myscript.py
which create the exe and dependent libraries in a directory.

and error :

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'h5py.defs'
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'h5py.utils'
I already imported h5py:
    import h5py
I used this command to resolve the error:

pyinstaller -w --hidden-import=h5py.defs --hidden-import=h5py.utils   myscript.py

and i got this error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'h5py.h5ac'

Comment: my suggestion was too long - moved it to answer. Sorry if it won't help.

Comment: It did helped. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 7):

If you get errors about `h5py` submodules, try to use [`collect_submodules` function](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/hooks.html) to add them all to `hidden_imports`.

You probably noticed a file called `myscript.spec` generated by a pyinstaller. Inside this file is an instruction on how to build you script (and it's just a python code too!).

So try to edit this `myscript.spec` like this:

```
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_submodules

hidden_imports = collect_submodules('h5py')

a = Analysis(['myscript.py'],
         binaries=None,
         datas=[],
         hiddenimports=hidden_imports,
         hookspath=[],
         runtime_hooks=[],
         excludes=[],
         win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
         win_private_assemblies=False,
         cipher=None)

# ... rest of a file untouched
```

Then run `pyinstaller` against that file: `pyinstaller myscript.spec`.

Comment: straight forward solution 

Comment: what modules should I place in hidden_imports? In my case problem is with pandas and something else. So I just wonder which else modules should I put into hidden?

Answer (score 2):

This resolved the error:

pyinstaller -w --hidden-import=h5py.defs --hidden-import=h5py.utils  --hidden-import=h5py.h5ac --hidden-import=h5py._proxy myscript.py