# Pyinstaller and sklearn.ensemble: 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.neighbors.quad_tree' [2760]'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, hook, pyinstaller

I have written a GUI in PyQt5 which includes the line
`from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier`.

Following the suggestion in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49444857/4451315), in `\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks`, I have added a file called `hook-pandas.py` which contains the following:

`hiddenimports = ['pandas._libs.tslibs.timedeltas',
                 'sklearn.neighbors.typedefs']`

After that, I tried running
`pyinstaller -F visual_vitals.py --hidden-import sklearn.neighbors.typedefs`
in the Anaconda Prompt.

However, I get the error
`RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`.

If, on the other hand, I just run
`pyinstaller visual_vitals.py'

then the .exe builds correctly, when I try running it, I get the message
`modulenotfounderror: no module named 'sklearn.neighbors.quad_tree'`.

What can I do about that?

Note that the problem disappears if, instead of a random forest, I use a support vector classifier, so the problem is specific to this classifier rather than to the whole of `sklearn`.

Comment: Probably [related](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/1138).

Answer (score 5):

I ran into the same problem with sklearn and pyinstaller.

Here is how I resolved it:

1.)Use command:

```
> pyi-makespec -F visual_vitals.py
```

2.)This will create a file by name vitals.spec

3.)Find line with

```
> hidden imports=[]
```

in the spec file.

Replace it with

```
> hiddenimports = ['pandas._libs.tslibs.timedeltas',
>                  'sklearn.neighbors.typedefs']
```

4.)Add these two lines to increase recursion limit at beginning of the spec file

```
> import sys 
> 
> sys.setrecursionlimit(5000)
```

5.)Run :

```
> pyinstaller visual_vitals.spec
```

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps anyone having

```
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.*'`

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'h5py.*'`
```

During or after building pyinstaller

Example if you get an error for `h5py`

After running `pyinstaller myscript.py` a `myscript.spec` is generated

Go inside `myscript.spec`

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

block_cipher = None

a = Analysis(['myscript.py'],
         binaries=None,
         datas=[],
         hiddenimports=[],
         hookspath=[],
         runtime_hooks=[],
         excludes=[],
         win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
         win_private_assemblies=False,
         cipher=None)
# ... rest of a file untouched
```

Add

```
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_submodules

hidden_imports = collect_submodules('h5py')
```

and

```
hiddenimports=hidden_imports,
```

Like this

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

block_cipher = None

from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_submodules

hidden_imports = collect_submodules('h5py')

a = Analysis(['myscript.py'],
         binaries=None,
         datas=[],
         hiddenimports=hidden_imports,
         hookspath=[],
         runtime_hooks=[],
         excludes=[],
         win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
         win_private_assemblies=False,
         cipher=None)
# ... rest of a file untouched
```

Then Save `myscript.spec` and run command `pyinstaller myscript.spec`

Credit to [9dogs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5827010/9dogs)
  [Pyinstaller created exe file can not load a keras nn model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45830206/pyinstaller-created-exe-file-can-not-load-a-keras-nn-model#answer-45842864)