# Is There any solution to solve this sklearn library problem?

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science

I'm trying to run the code for training model. And using sklearn library. I have install latest version of `sklearn` but this error occur.
`sklearn` error:

[image]

Comment: which sklearn version are you using ?

Comment: Is it the same issue as in https://stackoverflow.com/q/49558126?

Comment: yes YOLO. But the issue is resolved. I closed the ipython notebook and run it again then the issue is resolved. Thanks