# Pyinstaller, tensorflow.contrib lazy loader error at runtime

Tags: python, tensorflow, pyinstaller

Using the 3.3.1 pyinstaller in python 3.5 32bit, I converted a .py application to .exe

The application uses tensorflow and at some point throws

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "face_classify.py", line 140, in <module>
    loaded_model = load_c3d.c3d_model_obj(user_case)
  File "load_c3d.py", line 80, in __init__
    'wc1': _variable_with_weight_decay('wc1', [3, 3, 3, 3, 64], 0.0005),
  File "load_c3d.py", line 47, in _variable_with_weight_decay
    var = _variable_on_cpu(name, shape, tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
  File "site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 35, in __getattr__
  File "importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 956, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ImportError: No module named 'tensorflow.contrib'
```

This happens when running the .exe. Looks like a file path issue. The `__init__.py` of tensorflow does this

```
# Lazily import the `tf.contrib` module. This avoids loading all of the
# dependencies of `tf.contrib` at `import tensorflow` time.
  def __getattr__(self, item):
    global contrib
    # Replace the lazy loader with the imported module itself.
    import importlib  # pylint: disable=g-import-not-at-top
    contrib = importlib.import_module('tensorflow.contrib')
    return getattr(contrib, item)
```

To me it looks like this lazy loading cannot be tracked by pyinstaller. However the contrib folder is correctly placed inside my python installation: `C:\Python35\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib` How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case, you can add 'tensorflow.contrib' in your hiddenimport from the .spec file. However, I met another problem after I fix the import, but you can first try this at least.

Comment: We ended up removing the usage of tensorflow.contrib in the code (it was used to provide a random initialization). But your comment is useful. Upgrading Tensorflow (tried up to version 1.3) did not fix the issue btw.

Comment: I ended up manually adding all the .so file in the .spec file, and it works finally. In my case, the problem is that tensorflow contrib uses a tons of lazy loaders and relative path, so if you do not manually add all the files, pyinstaller cannot find them.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps anyone having

```
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.*'`

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'h5py.*'`
```

During or after building pyinstaller

Example if you get an error for `h5py`

After running `pyinstaller myscript.py` a `myscript.spec` is generated

Go inside `myscript.spec`

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

block_cipher = None

a = Analysis(['myscript.py'],
         binaries=None,
         datas=[],
         hiddenimports=[],
         hookspath=[],
         runtime_hooks=[],
         excludes=[],
         win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
         win_private_assemblies=False,
         cipher=None)
# ... rest of a file untouched
```

Add

```
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_submodules

hidden_imports = collect_submodules('h5py')
```

and

```
hiddenimports=hidden_imports,
```

Like this

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

block_cipher = None

from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_submodules

hidden_imports = collect_submodules('h5py')

a = Analysis(['myscript.py'],
         binaries=None,
         datas=[],
         hiddenimports=hidden_imports,
         hookspath=[],
         runtime_hooks=[],
         excludes=[],
         win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
         win_private_assemblies=False,
         cipher=None)
# ... rest of a file untouched
```

Then Save `myscript.spec` and run command `pyinstaller myscript.spec`

Credit to [9dogs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5827010/9dogs)
  [Pyinstaller created exe file can not load a keras nn model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45830206/pyinstaller-created-exe-file-can-not-load-a-keras-nn-model#answer-45842864)

Answer (score 0):

you can add ‘tensorflow.contrib’ to --hidden-import

`pyinstaller -F face_classify.py --hidden-import tensorflow.contrib`

Answer (score 0):

Even pyinstaller 4.0 (latest stable version today) has this error.
But there is a workaround if you don't use the --one_file.
Compile your program with --hiddenimports="tensorflow.contrib" and then copy all .so from tensorflow.contrib to where your executable looks for them. So, you need to create the contrib folder inside tensorflow and then copy the libraries.

```
mkdir path_to_dist/app_name/tensorflow/contrib
```

```
cd /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib && find ./ -name *.so |xargs -i cp --parents {} path_to_dist/app_name/tensorflow/contrib/
```

*change the python version if you are not using python 3.6.*

I don't know how to make this with --one_file.

Credits for andrewjong and aodiwei from github. The solution is on [this](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/2828) issue.